# Configuring WebDAV/SVN/Autoversioning/Windows

Tags: apache, svn, webdav, windows-explorer

I'm trying to setup a webDAV folder backed by SVN with autoversioning connected to by windows machines (mostly Win8).  I've done the following:

- Setup a WEbDAV with Digest authentication and WebDav On:

  ```
     <Location /general>
         DAV On
         AuthType Digest
         AuthName "general"
         AuthDigestDomain /general/
         AuthDigestProvider file
         AuthUserFile /var/www/webdav/general-webdav.pass
         Require valid-user
         ModMimeUsePathInfo on
  ```
- Made a password file as detailed above
- Connected to it with Cadaver
- Connected to it with Chrome on Windows
- Mapped a network drive and written to the folder

  So far so good; now to add SVN Autoversioning so I then did:
- Added dav_svn to apache2 - a2enmod dav_svn
- Modified the location as below to add in the SVN Path:

  ```
      <Location /general>
          DAV svn
          AuthType Digest
          AuthName "general"
          AuthDigestDomain /general/
          AuthDigestProvider file
          AuthUserFile /var/www/webdav/general-webdav.pass
          Require valid-user
          SVNPath /var/svn/repos/general
          SVNAutoversioning on
          ModMimeUsePathInfo on
  </Location>
  ```
- Made the svn directory of /var/svn/repos/general
- Created the svn repos : svnadmin create /var/svn/repos/general
- Changed the repos to be owned by www-data
- Checked out the repos
- Added and commited a test file to check it works
- Used Cadaver to connect to the repos/WebDAV dir - worked
- Used Chrome to connect to the repos/WebDAV dir - worked
- Used Windows Explorer on Win8 to connect to the repos/WebDAV dir - failed

  The apache access logs show that my windows box is talking to apache as shown by the following lines:

10.9.8.76 - - [28/Apr/2015:17:39:31 +0100] "OPTIONS / HTTP/1.1" 200 228 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.3.9600"

10.9.8.76 - - [28/Apr/2015:17:39:31 +0100] "PROPFIND /general HTTP/1.1" 401 825 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.3.9600"

10.9.8.76 - - [28/Apr/2015:17:39:36 +0100] "PROPFIND /general HTTP/1.1" 401 826 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.3.9600"

10.9.8.76 - benn [28/Apr/2015:17:39:36 +0100] "PROPFIND /general HTTP/1.1" 207 1641 "-" "Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.3.9600"

However Windows is not authenticating; it just gives me:

[image: WinEx Fail]
  Has anybody else successfully managed to get this to work?  The next task after this will be to write a python script to automate this whole lot which I'll open source but it's not worth doing it until the Windows Explorer to WebDAV/SVN is resolved.

Thanks for reading and any suggestions you may have.

Comment: WebDAV mini-redirector in Windows is FUBAR. The question has to be asked at ServerFault and there are a lot of similar ones actually, see http://serverfault.com/search?tab=active&q=webdav%20mini

Comment: See this one as well http://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/webdav-redirector-list.html

Comment: Thanks; I searched there and there is nothing specific for my own case.  I've decided to roll my own sub standard DeltaV server for my small company as I've already wasted quite some time on this so far